# Как создать условие "видно только админу"?

Tags: wordpress

Как для такого кода

```
/**
 * Wrap the default action HTML for .o2-resolve-link actions
 */
function wrap_post_action_html( $html, $action ) {
    if ( self::post_actions_key === $action[ 'action' ] && ! empty( $html ) ) {
        $html = "<span class='o2-resolve-wrap'>{$html}<ul></ul></span>";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

можно прописать условие, чтобы кнопку видели только админ и авторы записи (но главное админ, потому что он же единственный автор)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[current_user_can()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_user_can)** - Проверяет права текущего пользователя, совершать
 указанное действие.

```
/**
 * Wrap the default action HTML for .o2-resolve-link actions
 */
function wrap_post_action_html( $html, $action ) {
  if(current_user_can('administrator')){
    if ( self::post_actions_key === $action[ 'action' ] && ! empty( $html ) ) {
        $html = "<span class='o2-resolve-wrap'>{$html}<ul></ul></span>";
    }
    return $html;
  }
}
```

Comment: вот так работает. но тут вообще намека на is_admin() нету

Comment: @Chernikova еще раз,  is_admin() - Проверяет находится ли пользователь в админ-панели сайта (консоль или любая другая страница админки). Вам же нужно " current_user_can "

Comment: это да, тут не зависит в админке ли он или нет. запись и метка такая находятся в ленте записей блога.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверять возможности возможности роли, но ни в коем случае не её название.

Правильно: `if(current_user_can('manage_options'))`.

Неправильно: `if(current_user_can('administrator'))`.

Comment: так тоже сработало